# StaggeredGrid RecyclerView not showing anything

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to inflate a RecyclerView which has as StaggeredGrid Layout, but it is not showing anything. I've pretty much copied previous code I've used before for the RecyclerView so I'm kind of stumped.

In `MuseumStoriesViewHolder.onCreateViewHolder()` the return of holder has the following value `ViewHolder{337ec22b position=-1 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 unboundundefined adapter position no parent}` I'm not sure if this is realated, but it was something that seemed off to me.

It also might help to know that the fragment I'm inflating this RecyclerView is a nested Fragment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

MuseumFragment

```
    package com.example.android.radiobuttontestproject.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.android.radiobuttontestproject.R;
import com.example.android.radiobuttontestproject.adapters.MuseumStoriesAdapter;
import com.example.android.radiobuttontestproject.helpers.pojo.StoryObject;
import com.example.android.radiobuttontestproject.test.SampleDataFactory;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MuseumFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<StoryObject> storyObjectList;
    private StaggeredGridLayoutManager storyGridLayoutManager;
    private MuseumStoriesAdapter storyAdapter;


    @Bind(R.id.stories_recycler_view) RecyclerView storiesRecyclerView;

    public static MuseumFragment newInstance() {
        MuseumFragment fragment = new MuseumFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public MuseumFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_museum, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        //Sets up the stories
        SampleDataFactory sampleDataFactory = new SampleDataFactory();
        storyObjectList = sampleDataFactory.getSampleStories(
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test_titles_for_grid_museum1),
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test_desc_for_grid_museum1));
        storyGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        storiesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(storyGridLayoutManager);
        storyAdapter = new MuseumStoriesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), storyObjectList);
        storiesRecyclerView.setAdapter(storyAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

}
```

MuseumStoriesAdapter

```
package com.example.android.radiobuttontestproject.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.radiobuttontestproject.R;
import com.example.android.radiobuttontestproject.helpers.pojo.StoryObject;

import java.util.List;

public class MuseumStoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MuseumStoriesAdapter.MuseumStoriesViewHolder> {

    private List<StoryObject> itemList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private Context context;

    public MuseumStoriesAdapter(Context context, List<StoryObject> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public MuseumStoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_box_small, viewGroup, false);
        MuseumStoriesViewHolder holder = new MuseumStoriesViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MuseumStoriesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(itemList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.desc.setText(itemList.get(position).getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    class MuseumStoriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView type,title,desc;

        public MuseumStoriesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //Tried Butterknife, but it doesn't seem like it was working in the view holder. - Peter
            type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.small_box_type);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.small_box_title);
            desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.small_box_desc);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_museum.xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.radiobuttontestproject.fragments.MuseumFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/museum_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/header_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_larger"
            android:text="@string/museum_header" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/stories_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

view_box_small.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_box_margin"
    android:background="@color/small_box_background_color">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--TODO Make layout_height wrap contenet -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@color/test_color2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_off_mtrl_alpha"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/small_box_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_small"
        android:textColor="@color/font_red"
        android:text="Object"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/small_box_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_large"
        android:textColor="@color/font_black"
        android:text="Sample Text Here"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/small_box_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
        android:textColor="@color/font_black"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="Sample Text Here"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `ScrollView` in which you've wrapped the `RecyclerView`? Not sure if you did that intentionally, but nesting scroll containers is usually not what you want (with some specific use cases as an exception to that rule of thumb).

Comment: That did work thank you, but if I don't wrap it the `ScrollView` how do I make the `LinearLayout` scrollable? The `LinearLayout` is going to house more then shown in this snippet.

Comment: If the idea is to make the contents of the `LinearLayout` scroll with those of the `RecyclerView` (a 'header', so to speak), then the former should really become part of the latter. Basically the `LinearLayout` then becomes just another item inside the `RecyclerView` albeit with a different 'view type' (that's what the 2nd parameter in `onCreateViewHolder(...)` is for). You can do all this yourself (good exercise), or use a [library](https://github.com/blipinsk/RecyclerViewHeader) to make your life a bit easier.

Comment: I didn't realize that `RecyclerView` Was Scrollable I'm using recycler view to show 4-6 objects using the StaggeredGridView (Designed to look like Pintrest)  So there will actually be a couple recycler view on the page showing different sets of objects.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably not going to work like you intend it to... The problem with nesting scroll containers is the question of "who gets to scroll when". Even if you'd get them to lay out correctly, they'll all fight over the motion events. I'd suggest a single `RecyclerView` to display all the objects - even it's not immediately obvious how that would work, it would likely be the way to go. The only alternative I can think of is to simply inflate everything into a plain `ScrollView` (not using RecyclerViews), but - depending on the number of elements - that may be quite a performance hit.

Comment: Yeah there is about 12 different views (including what would be the various nested `RecyclerViews`) that need to go in the ScrollView. Thanks for the help.